# Why do I get a 11555 error on this SQL Server inline table valued function?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make this function an inline table-valued function on SQL Server 2016.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_GetBusinessRuleValue
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @FieldName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT
        FieldValue
    FROM 
        [BVI].[dbo].[BusinessRules] br
    WHERE 
        br.ClientID = DB_NAME()
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ActiveDate) <= 0
        AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), InactiveDate) >= 0 OR InactiveDate IS NULL)
        AND br.FieldName = 'ufn_GetBVIEmpType.Configuration'
)
```

When I try to create it with not null parameters I get the following error message:

> Msg 11555, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ufn_GetBusinessRuleValue, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 15]
>   The parameter '@FieldName' has been declared as NOT NULL. NOT NULL parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules, except for inline table-valued functions.

I thought this was an inline table-valued function. Is this not really an inline table-valued function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, your FieldName is hard coded in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `NOT NULL` because it is not supported with inline TVP:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_GetBusinessRuleValue
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @FieldName VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
```

> [CREATE FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):
>
> NULL|NOT NULL
>
> **Supported only for natively compiled, scalar user-defined functions.**

Comment: "except for inline table-valued functions.", what does it mean tho?